# Remove the leading brackets when used print in r

Tags: r, printing, cat

I' want to print the Sys.time() in r with no leading brackets.

For Example:

```
print(sprintf("Triggered at: %s", Sys.time()),quote = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
[1] Triggered at: 2018-04-30 10:51:12
```

But I want the outcome as

```
Triggered at: 2018-04-30 10:51:12
```

I've tried using cat for this but it was no use,

```
cat(Sys.time())
```

Output

```
1525058622
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there. Try

```
cat(sprintf("Triggered at: %s\n", Sys.time()))
#Triggered at: 2018-04-30 13:27:50
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, I wasted more than 1+ hours. Thank you! would accept the answer shortly(10 mins later), it is a system constraint.

Comment: *"I wasted more than 1+ hours."* Been there as well @Toros91;-)

Comment: There's also `message` - `message(paste0("Triggered at: ", Sys.time()))`

Comment: @SymbolixAU: Thank you, It is quiet interesting. Would keep this for future use.